# Choose N numbers in order to produce maximum equidistant numbers by summing the chosen numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

## Preliminaries

I have a device, an attenuator which is made up of resistive cells. To set the desired level of attenuation there are 7 switches on its front panel with the following values of attenuation (in dBs):
$$
{0.5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 20}
$$
These switches allow to choose the attenuation between 0 and 44.5 dB with the step of 0.5 dB.

I was wondering how the designers of this device have chosen those values. I was thinking that maybe they wanted to produce the maximum possible attenuation range with a step of 0.5 dB by means of 7 resistive cells. But then I realized that it was not the case because the following values produces a wider range:
$$
{0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}
$$
The range in this case is from 0 to 63.5 dB (and the step is still 0.5dB). There the problem came.

## Problem

Let's consider an $N$-tuple
$$
a(N) \in \mathbb{N}^N
$$
and a set
$$
S(a(N)) = \bigg\{\sum_{i\in p,\, p \in \mathcal{P}(\overline{[1,N]})} a_i \bigg | a_i \text{ is the $i$th coordinate of $a(N)$}\bigg\},
$$
where
$\mathcal{P}(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$ and $\overline{[1,N]}$  is $\{i|0 < i < N, i\in\mathbb{N}\}$
So $S(a(N))$ is the set of all possible sums of coordinates of $a(N)$ (including the empty sum).
Let's call an $N$-tuple $a(N)$ **good** if
$$S(a(N)) = \overline{[1,M]},\text{ for some } M\in\mathbb{N}$$
Let's denote the set of all good $N$-tuples as $G(N)$.
For example, the tuple $a=(1,2,3)$ is good because $S(a) = \{1, 2,3,4,5,6\}$. On the other hand the tuple $b=(1,2,5)$ is not good because $S(b) = \{1,2,3,5,6,7,8\}$ and 4 is missing.

> Given $N \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that
> $$\bigg [a(N)\in G(N) \text{ and } \sum_i a_i  = \max_{a(N)\in G(N)}({\max_{s_i \in S(a(N))}s_i})\bigg] \iff \bigg[a(N) = (1, 2, 4, ..., 2^{N-1})\bigg]$$
> In other words, a good $N$-tuple with the maximum possible sum of its coordinates is $(1,2,...,2^{N-1})$.

## Proof

I will prove the statement by induction. *Without loss of generality, it is assumed that the coordinates of tuples is sorted in the ascending order*.
The base case $N=1$ is obvious.
Let's suppose that the statement is true for all $k\leq N$. Then consider the case for $N+1$. Suppose that in this case the desired tuple $a\neq (1,2,4,...,2^{N})$. Then take the tuple $a' = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_N)$ i.e. $a$ without the last coordinate. There are two possibilities here:

*Case $a' = (1,2,4, ..., 2^{N-1})$*. In this case $S(a)$ looks like this:
$$
S(a) = \{ \color{red}{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., (2^N-1)}, \color{blue}{(a_{N+1} + 0), (a_{N+1} + 1), (a_{N+1} + 2), ..., (a_{N+1} + 2^N - 1)}\},
$$
where red elements are those obtained only from $a'$ and blue - are those obtained from the rest ($a_{N+1}$ and $a'$). Due to our convention we know that $a_{N+1} \geq a_{N}$. Therefore, taking into account the fact that $a$ is a good tuple, we conclude that $\color{blue}{a_{N+1}+0}$ must be equal to $\color{red}{2^N-1} + 1$. *Of course, the reds and blues might intersect but in this case the sum of all coordinates wouldn't be the maximum sum*. I.e.
$$
a_{N+1} = 2^N
$$
This contradicts the initial suggestion that $a$ is not $(1,2,4, ..., 2^N)$.

*Case $a'\neq (1,2,4, ..., 2^{N-1})$*. In this case $S(a)$ is the following (if $a\in G(N+1)$ then $a'\in G(N)$, see **Update**):
$$
S(a) = \{\color{red}{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., M}, \color{blue}{(a_{N+1} + 0), (a_{N+1} + 1), ..., (a_{N+1} + M)}\},
$$
where the colors have the same meaning as in the previous case and
$$
M < 2^N - 1\quad \text{by induction}
$$
Using the same reasoning as in the previous case we conclude that
$$
a_{N+1} = M + 1
$$
So
$$
\sum_i a_i = 2M + 1 < 2^{N+1} - 1
$$

---

## Update

If $a\in G(N+1)$ then $a'\in G(N)$. I thought it was true but now I cannot prove it :). But this doesn't really violate the proof I provided: suppose that $a'\notin G(N)$ then there is a gap between 0 and $M$ (red numbers), and therefore at least one of the blue sums must fill this gap. So in this case the maximum would be even smaller.

---

Is my proof a valid one? I am asking because I feel a bit uncomfortable that I don't proof the $\Leftarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$ separately.
I feel that this "fact" has a more elegant proof. Could you provide your own?

Comment: With $N$ switches, there are $2^N$ switch settings, so at best you can have $2^N$ distinct numbers. Assuming positive weights and a step size of one, that means at best you can create the range $[0, 2^N-1]$, and clearly using the powers of two will produce this range. The only thing left to prove is uniqueness, and for that induction is probably easiest. My first instinct would be to remove the smallest weight, which must be $1$, instead of the largest weight like you did.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was writing this proof when I saw your comment =)

Comment: And my proof is incorrect I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the proof I provided in the post is not correct.

---

The conventions and notations are the same as in the post. Also let's denote the set of $N$-tuples which coordinates are distinct powers of two as $B(N)$ so
$$
B(N) := \{a\in \mathbb{N} | a_i = 2^{i-1} \}
$$

---

It is obvious that
$$
|\mathcal{P}(\overline{[1,N]})| = 2^N
$$
So the maximum possible number in $S(a):a\in G(N)$ is $2^N -1$. This is because there are at most $2^N$ numbers in $S(a)$ for any $a\in \mathbb{N}^N$. But for good $N$-tuples these numbers are consequent from 0 to $M$. So the maximum possible $M$ will be for $a\in G(N)$ for which $S(a)$ contains exactly $2^N$ elements (i.e. there are no duplicates).

So we prove
$$
\big[ a\in G(N)\, \wedge\, \max S(a) = 2^N - 1\big] \iff a\in B(N)
$$

($\Leftarrow$). Obviously, the tuple $a = (1, 2, 4, ..., 2^{N-1})$ doesn't duplicate elements in $S(a)$. And
$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n<2^{N} \quad\exists s\in S(a) : s = n$$
So this $N$-tuple possesses the desired feature.

($\Rightarrow$). Suppose that there exists an $N$-tuple $b\notin B(N)$ such that $$\max_{s_i\in S(b)}s_i = 2^{N} - 1$$
Without loss of generality we assume that
$$b_N \neq 2^{N-1}\tag{1}\label{one}$$
Indeed, otherwise we throw away $b_N$ and consider $b' = (b_1, b_2, b_3, ..., b_{N-1})$ such that its maximum is $2^{N-1}-1$ and the problem stands the same.

Let's consider the tuple $b'=(b_1, b_2, ..., b_{N-1})$. We know that $|S(b')| = 2^{N-1}$. What is the maximum of $S(b')$.

*Case 1.* $\max S(b') = 2^{N-1} -1$. Then we obtain $b_N = 2^{N-1}$. Contradiction with \ref{one}.

*Case 2.* $\max S(b') < 2^{N-1} - 1$. Then $b_N > 2^{N-1}$. But then gaps are guaranteed (e.g. the number $2^{N-1} - 1$ would not appear in $S(b)$).$\tag{*}\label{aster}$

*Case 3.* $\max S(b') > 2^{N-1} - 1$. Then $b_N < 2^{N-1}$. We notice that $S(b)$ divides into two disjoint subsets
$$
S(b) = S(b') \cup S(b)\setminus S(b')\tag{**}\label{twoaster}
$$
In $S(b')$ are the sums which are obtained *only* from $b'$ and in $S(b)\setminus S(b')$ are the sums which are of the form $b_{N} + X, X\in S(b')$ so, obviously,
$$
\overline{[0, b_{N} - 1]} \subset S(b')\tag{2}\label{two}
$$
But then
$$
\overline{[b_{N}, 2b_{N} -1]} \subset S(b)\setminus S(b')\tag{3}\label{three}
$$
Those numbers may fill the entire set $S(b)$ but then $2b_{N} - 1 = 2^{N} - 1$ so $b_{N} = 2^{N-1}$. Contradiction with \ref{one}. Therefore there are more numbers in $S(b)$. The next one is $2b_{N}$ and it is, obviously, lies in $S(b')$. And then $3b_{N}$ is also in $S(b)$ and lies in $S(b)\setminus S(b')$. But then all the numbers between $2b_{N}$ and $3b_{N}$ are also in $S(b)$:
$$
\overline{[2b_N, 3b_N-1]}\subset S(b')\tag{4}\label{four}
$$
But then
$$
\overline{[3b_N, 4b_N-1]}\subset S(b)\setminus S(b')\tag{5}\label{five}
$$
Again it may be the entire $S(b)$. Then $b_N = 2^{N-2}$. Acting in the same manner one can prove that
$$
b_N = 2^K, K < N-1\tag{6}\label{six}
$$
*I feel that there should be a shorter proof using \ref{six} but I couldn't find it.*

We see that the last element $b_{N}$ divides the entire range into equal intervals of length of $2^{K}$.
Let's look at the first such interval $I_1 := [0, b_{N}-1]$ together with the tuple $b'' = (b_1', b_2', ..., b_{N-2}')$ i.e. $b'$ without its last element. Obviously, $S(b'')\subset S(b')$ and $S(b')$ itself can be represented as a union of two disjoint subsets (cf.\ref{twoaster}):
$$
S(b') = S(b'') \cup S(b')\setminus S(b'')
$$
But more important, $I_1\subset S(b')$ is also divided by $b_{N-1}$ into two subsets
$$
\overline{[0, b_{N}-1]} = A \cup B, A\subset S(b''), B\subset S(b')\setminus S(b'')
$$
The first we can say is that $B\neq \emptyset$. Indeed if it was so it would mean that the tuple $S(b'')$ fills the entire interval including the number $b_{N}-1$ but then adding $b_{N-1} < b_{N}$ to it would give the number between $b_{N}-1$ and $2b_{N}$ which is in contradiction with \ref{three}. So we know that

$$
\max_{s_i''\in S(b''),s_i''\in I_1} s_i'' < b_{N} -1
$$

More over, it must be greater then or equal to $b_{N}/2 - 1$. Otherwise, $S(b')$ wouldn't fill the entire interval (cf.\ref{aster}):
$$
b_{N}/2 - 1 \leq \max_{s_i''\in S(b''),s_i''\in I_1} s_i'' < b_{N}-1
$$
Using the same reasoning as in the first part of this proof one can show that

$$
b_{N-1} = 2^{K}, K\leq N-3
$$
And eventually
$$
b_{i} = 2^{K_i}, b_{N}  < 2^{N-1}, i < j \Rightarrow b_{i} < b_{j}\tag{7}\label{seven}
$$
But this makes no sense.